# Difference between React useCallback with pure function declared inside and outside component

Tags: reactjs, react-usecallback

Will there be a difference between these two approaches?:

```
// outside component
const magicIdx = (i) => (i - 1) / 3

//inside component
const calcIdxOut = useCallback(magicIdx, [])
const calcIdxIn = useCallback((i) => (i - 1) / 3, [])
```

Does defining a pure function outside the component and using it in a useCallback without dependencies makes any difference?

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in using `useCallback` with a function declared outside of the component. The purpose of `useCallback` is to give referential stability to a function, even though that function is technically redefined every render. Since that only applies to functions defined *inside* the component, it does nothing useful here.

```js
// Stable reference - only declared once
function example() {}

function App() {
  // Unstable reference - redeclared each time App renders
  function example2() {}

  // Stable reference - even though example2 changes, 
  // example3 reference only changes if dependencies to useCallback change.
  const example3 = useCallback(example2, []);
}
```

So if the above examples make sense, you'll notice that `example` is already stable, so there's no reason to ever use `useCallback` on it.

Your function is not expensive, so unless the purpose here is to prevent a memoized child component from re-rendering, referential stability really isn't a large concern anyway.

Comment: That's not strictly true. A function can be defined outside the component using `useCallback`, but still being recreated on every render in a parent component. I think it's important to discriminate this. If a function is created _outside all components which are parent components or aren't being memoized with the same dependencies_, then `useCallback` is not necessary. Otherwise, it is still potentially a useful optimization: it depends on exactly where the callback function in question is being instantiated.

Comment: I feel like saying outside the component, along with the example showing it, implies that we are talking about outside *all* components. `useCallback` is rarely used effectively anyway, since most people don't understand that the child component needed to be memoized for it to be helpful.